# Filtering many-to-many relationthip

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I make api with `rest-framwork` for `django 3`

I have a model which has many-to-many relationship.

then, now I want to use filter for many-to-many

in `models.py`

```
class Text(models.Model):
    t_id = models.CharField(unique=True,null=False,max_length=20)
    t_text = models.TextField(null=True)
    issues = models.ManyToManyField(Issue) # It is many-to-many relationship
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):    
        return self.t_id  


class Issue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=255)
    aka = models.CharField(max_length=2000,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

in `serializer.py`

```
class TextFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    t_text = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='contains') # it works
    issues = filter.***Filter # How should I do here??

    class Meta:
        model = Text
        fields = ('t_text','issues')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [`ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#modelmultiplechoicefilter) using for ManyToManyField:

```
class TextFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    t_text = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='contains') # it works
    issues = filter.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        field_name='issues__uuid',
        queryset=Issue.objects.all(),
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` works at first I don't understand the `issues__uuid` means but in my case `issues__name` works ( I should put `Issue` model code in article.)